# HandBrake strips out all my video

Tags: video-encoding, handbrake

I am using HandBrake for the first time because so far I have not been able to get any other encoder/converter to work.

I heard a bunch of good things about HandBrake so I am disappointed that I cant get it to work properly.

I have a 133MB WMV file that I want to convert to MP4 (h.254) for the web... except when I run the conversion all the video gets stripped and all I am left with is the audio?

I am using only the basic mp4 default settings.

**Does HandBrake not support WMV files?**

*Edit:  I used Windows Movie Maker as a quick cheap way to add some captions to the video... that's how I ended up with the WMV file.
If I just convert the raw MOV file (which came from the camera) its seems to work fine.*

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem.  When converting a WMV source file I got audio but no video.
I updated Handbrake to ver. 0.10.0.6534, which solved the problem.
After update, I can see, that frames are rendered and the time expected to do the job is realistic. Recoding worked without any problems.

Comment: Try not to answer with `Had the same problem`, just write out the solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On the Video tab, what's your **H.264 Level** set to?  Having too high of a level may be the cause of your video's disappearance.  I was compressing a large MP4 into a smaller one but had my **H.264 Level** set to the highest, 5.2 (in Handbrake v.0.10.5.0), and I would get an MP4 that only played audio in Media Player, but played just fine in VLC.  Just taking the level down to 5.1 solved the problem.

If that doesn't work, try converting videos with the predefined Presets until you find one that works, compare the differences between that preset and your own, then tweak those settings until you find the issue.  I used the *Universal* preset for my debugging.  I also recommend finding a small file to test with so that you can convert it within seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Handbrake does support WMV. I'm using the CLI to do this kind of task myself.

It would seem that your video codec is the cause of the issue. Can you convert files from another format (like MOV, for instance) to WMV successfully?